# AEM 6 + - Adobe sling login page should not show to users where session has timed out. Can I do it with the available config components?

Tags: aem, sling

How to redirect to a custom page instead of the sling login page when the session has timed out?
Is there any configuration that can be used from the available config components?
Or should I handle this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location of the login page through `com.day.cq.auth.impl.LoginSelectorHandler` by setting `auth.loginselector.defaultloginpage`
[image: login configuration]
If you need to do something more complicated, I would look into making a [custom authentication handler](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/authentication/impl/SampleLoginHookAuthenticationHandler.java).